# mootools radio button problem

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

I am a newbie to mootools and web development also. I have read this pretty cool [blog](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-star-rating) 
and I want to extend the code to connect with a database to update the rating with a php file. but unfortunately my code not working means database is not updating. Can someone please explain me why. Thanks a lot...

Here's the code

**star.html**

```
<html>

<script src="mootools-1.3.js"></script> 
<script src="lorenzos-MooStarRating-422072a/Source/moostarrating.js"></script> 
<script> 

    // Configure the image paths
    var MooStarRatingImages = {
        defaultImageFolder: 'lorenzos-MooStarRating-422072a/Graphics/',
        defaultImageEmpty:  'star_empty.png',
        defaultImageFull:   'star_full.png',
        defaultImageHover:  "star_boxed_hover.png"
    };

    // Post iD
    var postId = 10;

    // When the DOM is ready....
    window.addEvent("domready",function() {

        // Create our instance
        // Advanced options
        var advancedRating = new MooStarRating({
            form: 'ratingsForm',
            radios: 'rating',
            half: false,
            //imageEmpty: 'star_boxed_empty.png',
            //imageFull:  'star_boxed_full.png',
            //imageHover: "star_boxed_hover.png", 
            width: 17, 
            tip: 'Rate <i>[VALUE] / 7.0</i>', 
            tipTarget: $('htmlTip'),
            tipTargetType: 'html', 
            click: function(value) {
                // Send ajax request to server
                new Request.send({
                    url: "rateSave.php",
                    data: {'rating': value}
                });
            }
        });



    });

</script> 

<form name="ratingsForm">
<label>Select The Number of Stars</label>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1.0" checked="checked">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2.0">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3.0">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4.0">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5.0">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="6.0">

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="7.0">

<!--<input type="radio" name="rating" value="7.5">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="8.0">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="8.5">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="9.0">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="9.5">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="10.0">-->



<span id="htmlTip"></span>
</form>

</html>
```

**rateSave.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("rating", $con);

$starCount =$_POST['rating'];

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO star VALUES('hotel','$starCount')");



mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You mention that the DB is not updating but are there any error messages?

Comment: no there is no error message displaying... I can't figure out why this happens :-(

Comment: Have you checked the values actually submitted with POST are containing the data you expect?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code; consider using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for `POST` and `GET` data, or use PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi Pavithra Gunasekara, the error is 'nothing', here :

```
click: function(value) {
// Send ajax request to server ...
}
```

instead of 'click', the name of the CallBack function is onClick i.e.

```
onClick: function(value) {
// Send ajax request to server ...
}
```

about the 'click', you could do this way i.e.

```
advancedRating.addEvent('click', function(){ new Request.send({/* ... */}) });
```

working example with 'onClick' instead of the 'click' inside the new instance definition: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/LDw4y/

Comment: This is not right; it is `click`: https://github.com/lorenzos/MooStarRating/wiki/docs

Comment: It's not correct man :) ..if u want to use click inside the new instance definition, u have to use 'onClick'.. try it ;) 
If u want to add the click once u have the instance, u have to use addEvent('click',foo)

Comment: Then explain why this works, which is the exact same as above, which also happens to gibe with the documentation: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/mootools-star-rating.php

Comment: There is no click callback man!!!! try this out => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/LDw4y/

Comment: You're right. Here is another demo which demonstrates your point as well: http://jsfiddle.net/UJJN7/3/

Comment: Yes.. btw, Pavithra could put an alert inside the function to see that nothing happened :D

Comment: +1 @stecb ... people really ought to understand how mootools classes work with the `Events` and `Options` mixin classes. to pass on a callback to event `awesome` you do `onAwesome: function`. it's _that_ simple, given that the class instance will at some point do `this.fireEvent('awesome')`. i sugest you take the time to read a few mootools tutorials on the subject, the 30 mins it would take will make you a better programmer...